# VirtualHost with mod rewrite pointing at tomcat application

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, tomcat, mod-rewrite

I am setting up a server running on Ubuntu 14.04. I have apache and tomcat installed with the rewrite module for apache and mod_jk enabled.  I have mod_jk properly configured so apache is forwarding the request to the app context correctly.  I also have the domain name pointed correctly at the server and am able to browse to it. However, I am having issues with my virtual host file.  I am attempting to point a domain at the application running within tomcat.  Here is what I have currently as a virtual host file.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule \/$ /context [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

I have tried many variations of this but have had no luck.  Any help to resolve would be most appreciated.

** Update **

I am able to produce a rewrite to a directory named after the tomcat application, in this example `context` in my apache html folder `(/var/www/html/context)`.  Here is what my virtual host file now looks like :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>                                                       
        ServerName www.domain.com                                
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/context/  

        <Directory />                                                    
                Options FollowSymLinks                                   
                AllowOverride None                                       
                RewriteEngine On                                         
                RewriteRule \/$ /context [L]                                
        </Directory>                                                     

        <Directory /var/www/html/context/>                                  
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews                
                AllowOverride None                                       
                Order allow,deny                                         
                allow from all                                           
        </Directory>                                                    
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem now is it is not rewriting to the tomcat application named `context`. So to sum it all up :

`http://{{ip_address}}/context` - works like it should and displays the tomcat application

`http://domain.com` - redirects me to html content within `/var/www/html/context`

How can I force the rewrite rule to redirect to the tomcat application name `context`?  Is there a global setting that will override rewrites and instead of displaying content within apaches html directory to applications mounted with mod_jk?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited my virtual host file.  I added the JkMount inside the virtual host file instead of 000-default.conf and was able to get apache to pass the request to the tomcat application instead of the folder in apaches web directory.  I also now have 2 virtual host files, one for the main domain and the other for the domain without www. prefix.  Here is what the 2 files look like :

**www_domain.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerName www.domain.com

        JkMount /context* ajp13_worker

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule \/$ /context [L]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

**domain.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName domain.com

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule \/$ http://www.domain.com [L] 
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update2**

```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.domain.com
        ServerAlias 10.10.10.10(server's IP) server'sFQDN 
        DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

        RewriteEngine On
        # Rewrite everything after ' / ' to /context/restofURLifany
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /context/$1 [L,QSA,PT]
        # Rewrite ' / ' to /context
        #RewriteRule ^/$ /context [L,PT]
        # Send all '/context' traffic to prod loadbalancer ' prod_lb '
        JkMount /context prod_lb

        # Send all other traffic from root domain ' / ' to prod loadbalancer ' prod_lb '
        JkMount /* prod_lb

    </VirtualHost>
```

Edit `/etc/hosts` and add a line like this at the top:

```
#IPaddr hostnames
10.10.10.10 serverFQDN hostname www.domain.com
```

I'm assuming your problem is that the domain name you are using apache isn't associating with that virtual host.

In `httpd.conf` add: `NameVirtualHost *:80`

**Update**

Is this what you are looking for?

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /context/$1 [L,QSA,PT]
```

If you have mod_jk installed, this should help point you in the right direction:

**In virtualhost conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain

    # Send all traffic from root domain ' / ' to prod loadbalancer ' prod_lb '
    JkMount /* prod_lb

</VirtualHost>
```

**In workers.properties file**

```
# Define list of workers that will be used for mapping requests
worker.list=prod_lb,status

# Define Tomcat App Node1
# modify the host as your host IP or DNS name.
worker.node1.port=9999 #AJP1.3 port Tomcat listening on
worker.node1.host=127.0.0.1 #Insert FQDN or IP here (I prefer IPs for speed)
worker.node1.type=ajp13
worker.node1.lbfactor=1
worker.node1.cachesize=1
worker.node1.max_packet_size=16384
worker.node1.connect_timeout=10000
worker.node1.prepost_timeout=10000
worker.node1.socket_timeout=5000
worker.node1.socket_keepalive=True
worker.node1.reply_timeout=30000
worker.node1.max_reply_timeouts=3
worker.node1.recovery_options=0
worker.node1.domain=group1
worker.node1.stopped=false

# Load-balancing behavior
worker.prod_lb.type=lb
worker.prod_lb.balance_workers=node1
worker.prod_lb.max_reply_timeouts=10
worker.prod_lb.method=Session
worker.prod_lb.lock=P
worker.prod_lb.sticky_session=1
worker.status.type=status
```

**Tomcat's server.xml**

```
<!-- Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port -->
<Connector port="9999" address="${jboss.bind.address}" protocol="AJP/1.3" 
   maxThreads="300" connectionTimeout="5000" maxHttpHeaderSize="16384" packetSize="16384" 
   emptySessionPath="true" enableLookups="false" />

<Engine name="jboss.web" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat_node1">
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried 'RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ /context/$1 [L,QSA,PT]' but produced 'The requested URL /context was not found on this server'.  However I can browse to http://{{ip_address}}/context without issue.